# Adding a JAR into the Android project's /libs folder

Tags: android, jar, noclassdeffounderror, libs

There are tons of questions about this, but none gives a clear solution to this problem (is it really so difficult?)

I'm trying to add a jar to my Android project. Since r17, Google says we should add the jars to `/libs` folder, and that the andriod tools will take care of the rest.

I have included a very big library, and it works good, except of one class, so I decided to try and make my own jar.

I created a new java project, and added a simple `Test` class. Then I exported it as a jar and manually copied the jar into the `/libs` folder. I cleaned and rebuilt my android app without problems, but at runtime, referencing the Test class, i get the following errors:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mytestpackage.Test

When I include the source of the jar into my project directly, it works (of course).

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after struggling with it for a day now, I found out that I had the compiler level set to 1.7 in the library project, so when I exported the jar, it was exported with a higher compiling level than what android supports (1.6).

So the solution, in the project of the jar to export:
`Properties` -> `Java Compiler` -> `Enable specific settings` -> `Compiler compilance level` -> 1.6

That fixed it for me, I hope it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Since r17, Google says we should add the jars to /libs folder, and that the andriod tools will take care of the rest.

Correct.

> So what am I doing wrong?

If I had to guess, in addition to copying the JAR to `libs/`, you *also* did "Add to Build Path" in Eclipse (per the other answer). Not only is that not necessary, but reports indicate that doing this somehow suppresses actually packaging the JAR from `libs/` into the APK. If indeed you did this, undo the manual build path change, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your .classpath. In Eclipse, mark the library (put in /libs) and `Right click->Build Path->Add to build path`